# dA in polar coordinates?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have seen a picture for $dV$ so that $dV = r^{2} \sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$. But how can I deduce things like $dA$ and $dV$? In a simpler coordinate (not sure about the name), $dA = r \,dr\,d\phi$, again no idea *how to derive it* (just given to me to memorize it). So explain what is $dA$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: I do not know the rigorous version of it, but since this comes from a physics background, this is mostly done by visualizing. dV is then the infinitesimal change in volume, which can be visualized as the volume of an element bound by $dr$ an arc $r\sin\theta d\theta$ and another $rd\phi$. For dA it depends which surface you're taking,  $dA=dr (rsin\theta d\phi)$ or $dA=dr (r d\theta)$ or $dA=(rd\theta) (r\sin\theta d\phi)$ if you keep $\theta$, $r$ fixed or $\phi$ fixed.

Comment: The area element $dA = r dr d\phi$ is from polar coordinates.  The boundaries are the radial $dr$ and the circumferential $rd\phi$

Comment: @Approximist: there is an err. I think it must be $r \sin(\theta) d\theta$, $dr$ and $r d\phi$. N.b. the term $r^{2}$. The last part about $dA$ got me confused. Could you explain it with general surfaces?

Comment: just a note, if you write $dA=r dr d\phi$ then you mean $\phi$ to be the polar angle. In the formula for dV you wrote $\phi$ would be the azimuthal angle. (@user error corrected)

Comment: There is no general expression for surface elements $dA$ (atleast, one like $dV$), since these depend on the orientation of the surface. You simply have to analyze the geometry for any given case If you are integrating over the surface of a sphere, for instance, then r is constant, whereas $\theta$ and $\phi$ change. That is the last expression for $dA$ I wrote in previous comment. On the other hand, if the surface lies in the xy plane, say, so that $\theta$ is constant ($\pi /2$) while $r$ and $\phi$ vary, then dA is the first of the dA's I wrote in comment.

Comment: @Approximist: I don't know but I feel that rcollyer is on the right track. But you have very good points like *"For dA it depends which surface you're taking, dA=dr(rsinθdϕ) or dA=dr(rdθ) or dA=(rdθ)(rsinθdϕ) if you keep θ, r fixed or ϕ fixed."* which I am still unsure, could you write them to an answer?

Comment: @user there is no general expression, but yes, a general sytematic method

Comment: @Approximist: technically there are some very nice general expressions for the element of surface area $dA$ for an arbitrarily parametrized surface (or even a $k$-manifold in Euclidean space).  The element of $k$-dimensional volume looks like $\sqrt{Det(J^tJ)}dx_1\cdots dx_k$ where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix (matrix of partial derivatives) of the function that parametrizes the manifold. $J^t$ is the transpose of $J$.

Comment: @Ryan yes I realized that a bit later :) thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Completing rcollyer's answer

$$\iint_S f(x,y) dx dy = \iint_S f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \det[J(u,v)] du dv$$

for 2-D polar coordinates $u=r$ and $v=\theta$

Find out $\det[J(r,\theta)] =r$

Therefore $dA= r dr d\theta$

So in general your area element is $dA=\det[J(r,\theta)] du dv$

Jacobians are used extensively in Statistical mechanics, but usually most physics problems come in flavors of one in three coordinate systems(cart, spherical, cylindrical) so we do not bother with the Jacobian when geometric intuition gets us the right answer for these three cases readily, which I have written in the comment.

**EDIT:**

The Jacobian is just a product of the scale factors when you change from one (orthogonal) coordinate system to another. Please note, that all this is a part of nonstandard analysis which exploits the notion of an infinitesimal. Start working from 2-D. Your area element would be a region bounded by the lines $x,x+\Delta x,y, y+\Delta y$ and your area element is $\Delta x \Delta y$. Finally take the limit in $\Delta x ,\Delta y\rightarrow 0$ and this is understood when you write $\int \int dx dy$. Repeat with polar coordinates. To locate a curve start with the constant coordinate $r$ which is a circle of radius $r$. Then draw a curve of constant $\theta$. This is a ray which goes from the origin to infinity making an angle $\theta$ with the positive x axis. Now draw another constant curve $r+\Delta r$ and $\theta + \Delta \theta$. Look at the intersection of these two. When you take the limits, this can be approximated as a rectangle, so, area is $\Delta r (r \Delta \theta)$. The factor $r$ which converts the infinitesimal change in $\theta$ ti the corresponding displacement $rd\theta$ is called the scale factor $h_\theta$. For an orthogonal system the jacobian is the product of scale factors. For spherical coordinate system it is easy to show  that:
$h_r=1, h_\theta=r, h_\phi=r \sin \theta $ so $J(r,\theta,\phi)=r^2\sin\theta$
For cylindrical $h_\rho=1,h_\phi=\rho,h_z=1$ etc..

Now regarding your question about the integral, consider a transformation of a cartesian coordinate $x$ to some new coordinate $\xi$, you know that

$$\int f(x) dx = \int f(x(\xi)) \frac{dx}{d\xi}d\xi$$

The jacobian is $J(\xi)=\frac{dx}{d\xi}$

For surface integrals,

$$\iint_S f(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2 = \iint_S f(x_1(\xi_1,\xi_2),x_2(\xi_1,\xi_2)) \det[J(\xi_1,\xi_2)] d\xi_1 d\xi_2$$

For volume integrals

$$\iiint f(x_1,x_2,x_3) dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 = \iiint f(x_1(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3),x_2(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3),x_3(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)) |J(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)| d\xi_1 d\xi_2 d\xi_3$$

**EDIT2**
As I mentioned in the earlier comment, when you have to find the surface element in a 3D coordinate system, you have to first know what your surface is. This would depend on what actually your finction $f(x,y)$ is. Mostly in physical problems, the surface is traced out by keeping one coordinate system fixed and varying the other two (examples- sphere's surface is fixed radii and varying azimuthal and polar angles, a plane's surface is a fixed polar angle and varying azimuthal angle and radial coordinate, etc...)

Comment: @Approximist: what is the integral called? Is the base transformation a *flux integral* in every case? I am not sure but cannot see a reason why the integral would not differ between *path* -, *line* -, *surface* - and *flux* -integral (and possibly other unknown to me in higher dim or more advanced base things).

Comment: @user: see edit

Answer (score 4):

The way to calculate this without appeal to a geometric construction is to use the [Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).  The Jacobian matrix is constructed by taking the partial derivative of the new coordinates ($\epsilon_i$) with respect to the old coordinates ($\delta_j$)

$$J_{ij} = \frac{\partial \epsilon_i}{\partial \delta_j}.$$

Answer (score 1):

To calculate this without using the Jacobian determinant. You can use the exterior derivative operator d to figure out this problem where for a function f $df = f_xdx+f_ydy+f_zdz$ We can use the other definitions of polar coordinates to solve for dx and dy in terms of r and $\theta$. Note that in this derivation we are using exterior products (Think cross product) of differentials not the usual point wise product and note: $dx\wedge dx = 0 $ and $dx\wedge dy = -dy \wedge dx$
$$
x = r\cos(\theta)
\\ y = r\sin(\theta)
\\ dx = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} r\cos(\theta)dr + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} r\cos(\theta)d\theta
\\ dx = \cos(\theta)dr - r\sin(\theta)d\theta
\\ dy = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} r\sin(\theta)dr + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} r\sin(\theta)d\theta
\\ dy = \sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta
\\ \text{Multiplication yields}
\\ dxdy = (\cos(\theta)dr - r\sin(\theta)d\theta) * (\sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta)
\\dxdy = \cos(\theta)dr*\sin(\theta)dr - r^2\sin(\theta)d\theta*\cos(\theta)d\theta-r\sin^2(\theta)d\theta dr+r\cos^2(\theta)drd\theta 
\\dxdy = 0 -0+r(\cos^2(\theta)drd\theta-\sin^2(\theta)d\theta dr)
\\dxdy = r(\cos^2(\theta)drd\theta+\sin^2(\theta)dr d\theta)
\\dxdy = rdrd\theta( \cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta))=rdrd\theta
\\\text{More accurately}
\\dx\wedge dy = rdr\wedge d\theta
\\\text{You can then integrate the differential 2-form}
\\ \int dx\wedge dy = \int rdr\wedge d\theta = \iint rdrd\theta
$$