# Applying Green's Theorem 3

Tags: greens-theorem

When using green's theorem to evaluate a line integral
$$\oint_C P\;dx + Q\;dy = \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\;dx\,dy$$
where $C$ is a circle, I know we have to use the cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$. My question is how do we change the $dx\,dy$ on the right hand side of the equation to $r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49927/why-is-dy-dx-r-dr-d-theta?lq=1

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You change the coordinates using a Jacobian determinant. 
\begin{gathered}
  x = r\cos \theta  \hfill \\
  y = r\sin \theta  \hfill \\
  \left| J \right|dxdy = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial r}}}&{\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial \theta }}} \\ 
  {\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial r}}}&{\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial \theta }}} 
\end{array}} \right| = \left( {\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial r}}\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial \theta }} - \frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial \theta }}\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial r}}} \right)drd\theta  = \left( {r{{\cos }^2}\theta  + r{{\sin }^2}\theta } \right)drd\theta  = rdrd\theta  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}