# Double integration over a ring area

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have an integral $\int_D\,\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ which I should integrate over $D$.

$D$ is limited by $1  \leq x^2 +y^2  \leq 4$ and $x \geq 0, y \leq 0$

I have plotted the limits and the integration should be between the circles in the down right quadrant.
[image]

**Update:** after hint of polar coordinate, limits and that $r$ should be $\frac{1}{r}$:

$$\int_D\,\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy = \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\,\int_1^2{}\,\frac{1}{r}drd\theta$$

finally correct? :)

Comment: Hint: Polar coordinates.

Comment: Normally in polar coordinates, $\theta=0$ is the $x$ axis and angles are measured counterclockwise.  The limits would then be $\frac {3\pi}2 \le \theta \le 2\pi$

Comment: Thanks for the polar hint and very much thanks for the riminder that angels are going counter clockwise I had a smaler blackout it seems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{1}{r^2}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}r=\dfrac{1}{r}$$

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37044/752) question.

ADDED. Your update is now correct: the integrand in polar coordinates becomes $1/r\;$  after the multiplication by $r$.

Comment: Big thanks in my haste I wrote r instead of $\frac{1}{r}$. Nicely spotted

Comment: @Farmor You are welcome.