# Show that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \mathbb{e}^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$ = $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explain $\iint \mathrm dx\mathrm dy = \iint r \mathrm d\alpha\mathrm dr$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37044/explain-iint-mathrm-dx-mathrm-dy-iint-r-mathrm-d-alpha-mathrm-dr)

**Show that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \mathbb{e}^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$ = $\sqrt{\pi}$.**

The hint was to calculate the double integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \mathbb{e}^{-x^2}\mathbb{e}^{-y^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ using polar coordinates. The double integral equals [$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \mathbb{e}^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x]^2$.

So I started by writing $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. I know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$.  Then I need to change those variables in my original equation, but this confuses me.

I get:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! \mathbb{e}^{-r^2}\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

I also got told that the double integral equals:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \! \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \! \mathbb{e}^{-r^2}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r$$

Why though?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The extra factor $r$ comes from the Jacobian of the change of variables. If you're uncertain, check your textbook, or (for example) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Change_of_variables

Comment: Are you asking why the double integral in Cartesian coordinates is equal to the double integral in polar coordinates?

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't think this is a duplicate since here the OP wants to know how $dx dy$ transformed into $r d r d \theta$.

Comment: Indeed, I want to know how to change dxdy into rdrdθ, and how to change my interval of integration.

Comment: The range in $\theta$ is $0$ to $2 \pi$ and $r$ is $0$ to $\infty$ to cover the plane

Comment: This was mistakenly closed as a duplicate.  But the content of this question is: Why does $dx\,dy$ become $r\,dr\,d\theta$?  The other question cited as an exact duplicate does not even mention that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin, if the angle $\theta$ is incremented by an infinitely small amount $d\theta$, then the infinitely small arc length involved is $r\,d\theta$.  An infinitely small increment $dr$ in $r$ is in a direction a right angles to the circle.  So you're looking at an infinitely small rectangle whose sides have lengths $dr$ and $r\,d\theta$, and whose area is therefore $r\,dr\,d\theta$.