# Using polar coordinates find area of $(x^2+y^2)^3=x^4+y^4$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Using polar coordinates find area of figure bounded by given curves.
$(x^2+y^2)^3=x^4+y^4$

Using polar coordinates I get $r^2=\cos^4\phi+\sin^4\phi=\frac{3+\cos4\phi}{4}$

Now $0\leq\phi\leq2\pi$ but how get bounds for $r$?

Comment: Note that the figure bounded by that curve satisfies  $(x^2+y^2)^3 < x^4 + y^4$. Also the resulting integral isn't solvable in elementary functions.

Comment: @eyeballfrog So $0<r<\frac{\sqrt{3+cos4x}}{2}?$

Comment: Well it's $0 \le r$, but otherwise yes.

Comment: Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12r^2d\phi$.

Comment: @J.G. How you got that? And where is bounds for $r.$

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/405941).

Answer (score 2):

Polar coordinates give you $r^{6}=r^{4}(\cos^{4}(\theta)+\sin^{4}(\theta))$

This gives $r^{2}=(\cos^{4}(\theta)+\sin^{4}(\theta))$

Here's a nice picture

[image]

Now the area is given by

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{(\cos^{4}(\theta)+\sin^{4}(\theta))}}r\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}((\cos^{4}(\theta)+\sin^{4}(\theta))\,d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^{4}(\theta)\,d\theta $$ . I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating in [polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146249), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Area}
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{r(\theta)}r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12r(\theta)^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}
$$
The last equality is valid when $r$ can be expressed as a function of $\theta$ (e.g. when the curve circles the origin).

As has been mentioned,
$$
r^2=\frac{3+\cos(4\theta)}4
$$
so we can compute the area as
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12r^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3+\cos(4\theta)}8\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{3\pi}4
\end{align}
$$