# How to prove $\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-c^2/a^2}c^4\,dc=\frac{3}{8}a^5\sqrt\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

How do i prove this integral can someone give me proof i've been trying this too long i tried direct integration by parts, differentiation all to no avail.Please support us :)

> $$\int^{\infty}_0 e^{\frac{-c^2}{a^2}}c^4\,dc=\frac{3}{8}a^5\sqrt\pi$$

Comment: [Parametric differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_using_parametric_derivatives) is how I would do this first and foremost, but I know of several ways.

Comment: @CameronWilliams could you solve it for me i'll very grateful.

Comment: Quanto just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, with
$I(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t x^2}dx= \frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt t }$
$$ I''(t) = \int_0^\infty x^4 e^{-t x^2}dx=  \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{8 \ t^{5/2}}$$

Thus

$$\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-c^2/a^2}c^4\,dc=I''(1/a^2)=\frac{3\sqrt\pi}{8}a^5$$

Comment: can you clarify it please ?

Comment: What method are you using is this Gaussian Integral ? but i get it.

Comment: @CarlJohnson - double integral $(\int e^{-u^2}du)^2 = \int\int e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta = \pi$

Answer (score 1):

Two times by parts:
$\int\limits_0^\infty e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}dx=
\left.xe^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}\right|_0^\infty+
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{2x^2}{a^2}e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}dx=
\frac{2}{a^2}\int\limits_0^\infty e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}d\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)=$
$
\frac{2}{a^2}\left(\left.\frac{x^3}{3}e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}\right|_0^\infty+\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot\frac{2x}{a^2}e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}dx\right)=
\frac{4}{3a^4}\int\limits_0^\infty x^4e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}dx$
Let alone [$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601418) or [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty+e%5E%7B-x%5E2%7Ddx) be a known result, we obtain
$$\int\limits_0^\infty x^4e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}dx=\frac{3a^4}{4}\int\limits_0^\infty e^\frac{-x^2}{a^2}dx=
\frac{3a^4}{4}\cdot a\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{3a^5\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\hbox{, QED}$$