# $3$ questions on change of variables: Jacobian absolute value, Jacobian = zero, Jacobian and differentials!

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to understand several aspects of Jacobian determinant in changing variables in multiple integral.

$[1]$ If I want to calculate double integral:
$$\iint_Rf(x,y)dxdy$$
and made a substitution:  $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$ then using chain rule:
$$dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv$$
$$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv$$

and then:
$$dxdy=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv\right)\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv\right)$$
$$dxdy=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du^2+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)dudv$$
how this last line could be rearranged to be equal the Jacobian:

$$J(u,v)=\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{array}\right|$$

$[2]$ Is there cases which its Jacobian $J(u,v)=0$ ? If so, what does this mean ?

$[3]$ Why when we change the variable and do the double integral we put the absolute value of Jacobian ?
$$ \iint_R\,f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \left| 
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right|\,du\,dv$$

Comment: Re (1), note that the rules to compute $dxdy$ are that $dudu=dvdv=0$ and $dvdu=-dudv$.

Comment: Why is that ? could you please explain ?

Comment: Related, the link given in a comment there included: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/37156/