# Volume element in Spherical Coordinates $dxdydz$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

So I know in Cartesian coords $dV = dxdydz$. I also know, that in Spherical coordinates, $dV = Jd\phi d\theta dx$ where $J =\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\phi,\theta)}$. However, when I find the differentials of x,y,z, as below,

$ =sincos,
=sinsin,
=cos$

$=sincos+coscos–sinsin$

$=sinsin+sincos+sincos$

$=cos–sin$

If I calculate $dxdydz$ it does not equal what it should equal. There are $dr^3$ and $d\theta^3$ terms included. I don't understand why this is true? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: Explanation for the planar case: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37156/1242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult the Wikipedia page, for instance.  Coordinate changes change the volume element by the jacobian.  Your expressions for $\operatorname dx, \operatorname dy$ and $\operatorname dz$ are correct.   But when you multiply them, you actually have an exterior, or wedge, product of differential forms.  Instead of $\operatorname dr^3$, you'll have $\operatorname dr\wedge \operatorname dr\wedge\operatorname dr=0$.  And so on.  I instruct you to do some reading on the subject.

Use the fact that the wedge product is anticommutative and you can get it to work out.

Maybe try *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak, among others.