# Surface integral of given vector field through a given surface

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

(Problem)

Evaluate the surface integral, where $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(x^2-y^2+y)\vec{i}+2xy\vec{j}+(y^2-z^2)\vec{k}$ and $S$ is the surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1,0 \leqq z \leqq 1$

I solved this question,but I'm worried if the answer is correct.

I would like to check my answer.

(My answer)

Let $V$ be the region enclosed by the surface $S$,and let $\vec{n}$ be the outward pointing unit normal.Then,the following formula holds.

$$\displaystyle\int\int_{S} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}\,dS=\int\int\int_{V} div\vec{F}dV$$

When calculating $\operatorname{div}\vec{F}$, it becomes as follows:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}\vec{F}
&=\displaystyle\frac{\delta}{\delta x}(x^2-y^2+y)+\frac{\delta}{\delta y}(2xy)+\frac{\delta}{\delta z}(y^2-z^2)\\
&=2x+2x-2z\\
&=4x-2z
\end{align}

Let $s(r,\theta,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$ be the parameterization of $S$.

The determinant of the Jacobian matrix is calculated as follows:

$$\left| \begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{dr} & \frac{dy}{dr} & \frac{dz}{dr} \\
\frac{dx}{d\theta} & \frac{dy}{d\theta} & \frac{dz}{d\theta} \\
\frac{dx}{dz} & \frac{dy}{dz} & \frac{dz}{dz}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|
=
\left| \begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0 \\
-r\sin\theta & r\cos\theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right|=r$$

Therefore, $dV=dxdydz=rdrd\theta dz.$

\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int\int\int_{V} \operatorname{div}\vec{F}dV
&=\displaystyle\int\int\int_{V} (4x-2z)dxdydz\\
&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(4r\cos\theta-2z)rdrd\theta dz\\
&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\frac{4}{3}r^{3}\cos\theta-r^{2}z\right]^{1}_{0}d\theta dz\\
&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{4}{3}\cos\theta -z\right)d\theta dz\\
&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{4}{3}\sin\theta -z\theta \right]_{0}^{2\pi} dz\\
&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left(-2\pi z \right) dz\\
&=\displaystyle\left[-\pi z^{2} \right]_{0}^{1}=-\pi
\end{align}

I think the answer is $-\pi$.Is this correct?

Comment: It is not. With your approach the area of a disk of radius $R$ came out to be
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi R
$$
but the correct integration is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R\color{red}{r}\,dr\,d\theta=\pi R^2\,.
$$ See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25671/da-in-polar-coordinates) for example.

Comment: I forgot $dxdy = rdrd\theta$.I corrected my answer.Is my answer correct?

Comment: The integral you have to evaluate is now correct. What have you learned if I say yes or no? What are smart steps to become 100% sure if $-\pi$ is correct?

Comment: Thank you.If your answer is No, I thought I need to check what's wrong.There is a possibility that I have a wrong understanding.I am very sorry if you feel uncomfortable about my question.

Comment: I do not feel uncomfortable about your question. Only about the fact that you need my confirmation whether the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r(4r\cos\theta-2z)\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$ is  $-\pi$ or not. If you tell us the steps that you performed there will in the end be no doubt about the correct result.

Comment: I editted my answer.I would like to confirm if there are any errors in the calculation of the surface integral.

Comment: Looks right. A tip: by doing Fubini there is a quick way to see that the integral of $\cos\theta$ is zero. What remains is essentially $$\int_0^1\int_0^1rz\,dr\,dz=\frac 14.
$$

Comment: I appreciate your kind response during your busy time.Thank you.